# Can't run Maven Spring MVC project in Tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am doing a Maven Spring MVC project following this instruction: http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-contentnegotiatingviewresolver-example/

After many times implementing this, I'm totaly fail. Could you help me to find what's problem here?

```js
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@1b083826]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
 at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:657)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@1b083826]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
 at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:709)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4748)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4880)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
 at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
 ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
 at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:113)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
 ... 33 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:111)
 ... 34 more

Aug 03, 2017 11:09:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:657)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:956)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
 at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
 ... 13 more

Aug 03, 2017 11:09:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:956)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:657)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
```

This is the link of my project: https://github.com/TranNgocKhoa/Spring-4-MVC-ContentNegotiatingViewResolver-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this solution.. which is found in other thread for a similar problem.

The main problem is corrupted jars.

To find the corrupted one, you need to add a Java Exception Breakpoint in the Debugger View of Eclipse, or your preferred IDE, select the  `java.util.zip.ZipException` class, and restart Tomcat instance.

When the JVM suspends at ZipException breakpoint you must go to `JarFile.getManifestFromReference()` in the stack trace, and check attribute name to see the filename.

After that, you should delete the file from the file system and then right click your project, select Maven, Update Project, check on Force Update of Snapshots/Releases.

Comment: You can also delete entire .m2 directory from file system and restart project. Maven will download everything what is needed again. It is time consuming to download everything again, but sometimes it happens to be more than one jar is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to run your code cloned from git hub it's work for me with url `http://localhost:8081/Spring4MVCContentNegotiatingViewResolverExample/pizzavalley/margherita.xml` I thing in your project there is any problem of tomcat or should be maven so please try to reinstall you tomcat and run `mvn clean` and then `mvn install` and then wait for downloading dependencies and then run project on server.